# Querying key value in List<string>

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var tuple = new Tuple<string, string>("MyKey", "MyValue");
var list = new List<string>();
var str = tuple.ToString();
list.Add(str);
// str has the value "(MyKey, MyValue)"
```

I have a predefined object where I need to use a list of strings.
I decided to use a Tuple but I am not sure how I can cast the str value back to a Tuple.

How can I store a key value in a List so that I can use lambda to query it e.g. by the key?

Comment: Why use a list of strings instead of a list of tuples? Converting them back and forth is wasteful.

Comment: List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>>

Comment: Why not `Dictionary`?

Comment: Why you need the string at all? You can use a `List<Tuple<string, string>>`

Comment: Hi @DavidG good point. I have a predefined object where I need to use a list of string.

Comment: So why do you need a tuple then?

Comment: I want to store key value information in one string value.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense at all. Keep the values in a `Dictionary<string, string>`, that way you can find the item you need by key very easily.

Comment: Yes I agree but I still need to use the predefined object, so I was wondering if I should serialze a dictionary, tuple, json as a string?

Comment: Why do you need to use this predefined object though? What is so special about this list of strings that you cannot change?

Comment: I am storing builddefintion in TFS api and I want to store a template name information in the tag property of the BuildDefinition.cs . This proprety is a List<string>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this code:

```
var tuple = new Tuple<string, string>("MyKey", "MyValue");
var list = new List<string>();
var str = tuple.ToString();
list.Add(str);
// str has the value "(MyKey, MyValue)"
```

Could be replaced by a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
values.Add("MyKey", "MyValue");
```

Then you can use linq to query the dictionary if you'd like to do so:

```
value = values.Where(x => x.ContainsKey("MyKey"));
```

You can get a list with all the keys as follows:

```
List<string> keys = values.Keys;
```

So no need to have a separate list for that.

If you want a list of string with two values separated  by a coma, the dictionary will do too:

```
List<string> keysValues = (from item in values
                                               select item.Key + "," + item.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Isma I need to store the information in a predefined object which has a List<string> property. Could I serialize the dictionary as a string and restore it.

Comment: You could serialize to json https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm

Comment: And when I search the list of strings, I would need to check if the string is json.

Comment: I think that is a different question, perhaps you can post a new one with your specific serialization problem and I might be able to help. What I proposed was to avoid using a list of tuples where you can use a dictionary instead.

Comment: After reading againg the question, I updated my answer with an example of how to get a list of strings with the key and value using a dictionary only.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dictionary.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary.Add("myKey", "myVal");

        if (dictionary.ContainsKey("myKey"))
            dictionary["myKey"] = "myVal1";
```

Comment: Don't use `Any` on a dictionary. Use `ContainsKey` or `TryGetValue`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok... will use... Is there any specific reason for it? Is ContaingKey faster?

Comment: sure, a dictionary is very efficient if you lookup by key, that's the sole purpose. Therefore you have to use `ContainsKey`/`TryGetValue`. If you use LINQ's `Enumerable.Any` you are using a loop to find the key. So it will have `O(n)` instead of `O(1)` complexity, where `n` is the number of key-value pairs in the dictionary. If the key doesn't exist `Any` has to enumerate the whole dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use a [Dictionary](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary). But if you really need to do it this way:

To transform from the `string` back to `Tuple` (assuming that the Key itself will never contain a commma+space):

```
        var tuple = Tuple.Create("MyKey", "MyValue");
        var list = new List<string>();
        var str = tuple.ToString();
        list.Add(str);
        // str has the value "(MyKey, MyValue)"
        Console.WriteLine(str);

        int comma = str.IndexOf(", ");
        string key = str.Substring(1,comma-1);
        string valuee = str.Substring(comma+2,str.Length-key.Length-4);
        var tuple2 = Tuple.Create(key, valuee);
        // 'tuple2' is now equal to the orignal 'tuple'
```

Comment: And when the key or value contains a comma?

Comment: If the value contains the comma, this will work. When the key contains it, then this code will not work. But I honestly don't think that will ever happen in his case.

Comment: Ah yes, famous last words in software development "I honestly don't think that will ever happen". Those words are almost always followed by "Well damn, it did happen"

Comment: Why and when would a Key contain a comma?

Comment: Why wouldn't it contain a comma? Neither you or I have any idea how the OP is going to use this code. Or how the next person looking at this question will use it. Always assume the worst when writing your code. It's called [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming)

Comment: You don't need to educate me on different programming designs. I changed the code so that it searches for the index of comma+space. Otherwise, it isn't even possible to distinguish between the key and the value if the key contains comma+space.

Comment: You've just moved the goalposts for me to ask "what if the key contains comma-space? The point is that OP shouldn't be doing this in the first place. It's terrible practice.

Comment: Indeed it is, but he states that he is forced to do it this way, and this code will do it. Assuming that the key does not contain comma+space, because if it does, it is not even possible to do it.